Eleventy not updating changes from src folder to public folder
I just started working with Eleventy and everything was working fine till I came to the point where my public folder is not getting updated when I make changes in the src folder.
This is my code so far.
index.njk
---
title: PaperJourney
layout: 'base.njk'
cssFile: 'index.css'
---

<!-- Header -->
        <section class="header">
            <h1>PaperJourney</h1>
            <h4>Welcome to my blog, where every post is a journey through the realms of literature.</h4>
        </section>
        <hr>

<!-- Content -->
        <section class="content">

<!-- Content Left -->
            <div class="left-content">
                <h2>Latest Post</h2>
                <div class="latest-post">
                    <img class="latest-post-img" src="assets/img/br-misery-stephen-king.jpeg" alt="Misery book in black cover">
                    <h3><a href="pages/posts/post-template.html">Thrilling Tale: A Review of 'Misery' by Stephen King</a></h3>
                    <p>Discover the chilling tale of Misery by Stephen King, a psychological thriller that will keep you on the edge of your seat. Dive into the twisted world of renowned author Paul Sheldon as he is held captive by his number one fan, Annie Wilkes. Will Sheldon be able to escape the clutches of his deranged captor? Find out in this gripping novel that will leave you questioning the power of obsession and the depths of human depravity.</p>
                    <a class="read-more-btn" href="pages/posts/post-template.html">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>

<!-- Content Right -->
            <div class="right-content">

<!-- Popular Posts -->
                <div class="popular-posts">
                    <h5>Featured Posts</h5>
<!-- Popular Post 1 -->
                    <div class="post">
                        <a href="pages/posts/dune-br.html">
                            <div class="post-img"><img src="assets/img/dune-br-img.jpg" alt="Dune picture"></div>
                            <p class="popular-post-caption">"Dune" - A book review</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
<!-- Popular Post 2 -->
                    <div class="post">
                        <a href="pages/posts/fourth-wing-br.html">
                            <div class="post-img"><img src="assets/img/fourth-wing-br-img.jpg" alt="fourth wing picture"></div>
                            <p class="popular-post-caption">"Fourth Wing" - A book review</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
<!-- Popular Post 3 -->
                    <div class="post">
                        <a href="pages/posts/benefits-social-life-dl.html">
                            <div class="post-img"><img src="assets/img/social-groups-dl-img.jpg" alt="social groups picture"></div>
                            <p class="popular-post-caption">The benefits of social life</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
<!-- Popular Post 4 -->
                    <div class="post">
                        <a href="pages/posts/10-tips-usa-trip-travel.html">
                            <div class="post-img"><img src="assets/img/tips-usa-travel-img.jpg" alt="usa tips picture"></div>
                            <p class="popular-post-caption">10 tips for your trip to the USA</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

blog.njk
---
title: Blog
layout: 'base.njk'
cssFile: "blog.css"
---

<!-- Header -->
<section class="header">
    <h1>Blogposts</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Book Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Movie Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Daily Life</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
<hr>

<section class="blog-card-main">

    {%- for post in collections.post | reverse -%}
    <section class="blog-card">
        <img src="{{ post.data.image }}" alt="{{ post.data.imageAlt }}">
        <div class="blog-content">
            <h2 class="blog-title">{{ post.data.title }}</h2>
                <p class="publication-time">{{ post.date | postDate}}</p>
                <p class="blog-description">{{ post.data.description }}</p>
                <a class="read-more-btn" href="{{ post.url }}">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </section>
    {%- endfor -%}
    
</section>

article.njk
---
layout: 'base.njk'
cssFile: 'post.css'
---

<article class="main-article article">

    <div class="article-head">
        <div class="article-head-left">
            <h1 class="article-title">{{ title }}</h2>
            <h2 class="article-subheader">{{ description }}</h2>
            <span class="article-author">Written by <a href="#">{{ author }}</a></span>
            <p class="publication-time">{{ page.date | postDate }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article-head-right">
            <figure class="main-article-figure">
                <img src="{{ image }}" alt="{{ imageAlt }}">
                <figcaption>{{ imageAlt }}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>


    <!--<style>
        .article-content {
            width: 60%;
            height: auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            font-family: 'Baskerville', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            line-height: 1.5;
            text-align: justify;
            text-align-last: none;
        }

        .article-content::first-letter {
            initial-letter: 3;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 0.75rem;
        }
    </style>-->

    <article class="article-content">
        {{ content | safe }}
    </article>

</article>

.eleventy.js
const {DateTime } = require("luxon");

module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
    
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('/src/css/public-css/reset.css');
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('/src/css/public-css/main.css');
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('/src/css/page-css/{{ cssFile }}');
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('/src/assets');
    
    eleventyConfig.addFilter("postDate", (dateObj) => { return DateTime.fromJSDate(dateObj).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_MED);
})

    return {
      dir: {
        input: "src",
        output: "public"
      }
    }
  };

I was checking the .eleventy.js file so far but can't find anything.
I also uploaded everything in my public repository.
text

You are still using this {{ cssFile }} in your .eleventy.js. As mentioned in your other question you will have to remove it and try to copy /src/css/page-css only instead.
